# ClickOnce Install From URL Failing

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I have a WinForm application that I have been installing using ClickOnce from a URL for a few years without any issues.

All of a sudden I am now getting the following error when I try and do an installation...

"Application download did not succeed. Check your network connection, or contact your system administrator or network service provider"

On clicking on the Details button it displays the following error...

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\AppXYZ Dot Net 4.5\AppXYZ 4.5.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Downloading https://www.ABC.co.uk/_Application/Application Files/AppXYZ Dot Net 4.5_1_0_0_79/bin/Debug/AppXYZ Net 4.5.vshost.exe.deploy did not succeed.
+ The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.

I have checked the URL path to ensure that the AppXYZ Net 4.5.vshost.exe.deploy file is present and it is.

I have also successfully installed the ClickOnce application from a location on the PC. So the compiled files are all fine.

Any ideas why I am getting this 410 error?

Comment: Additional information:
I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling.
Also fully disabling Norton 360 (anti virus and firewall)

Answer (score 0):

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `410 Gone` client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent. Make sure such files exist on the server.

Comment: I did check at the time and the target resource was present.

Comment: Do you get any errors with a newly created ClickOnce installer? Is the error specific to your installer?

Comment: I continued to have problems, so I started installing the ClickOnce App from a local  file path (USB thumb drive). This was problem free. I have not had time to go back and try installing from a remote URL again.

Comment: Do you get any errors with a newly created ClickOnce installer?